# C# Open Windows explorer is slow

Tags: c#, windows, performance, explorer

I usually use this pierce of code to open a Window with a selected file:

```
public Process OpenWindowExplorerSelectingFile(string filePath)
{
  return Process.Start("explorer.exe", $"/select,\"{filePath}\"")
}
```

The point is that it freezes the UI for like 5 seconds +  it takes 1-2 additional seconds to show the window.
This behaviour is very uncomfortable.

I came up with the idea to make it work async to avoid UI blocking:

```
public static Task<Process> OpenWindowExplorerSelectingFileAsync(string filePath)
{
    return Task.Run(() => OpenWindowExplorerSelectingFile(filePath));
}
```

This alternative, doesn't freeze the UI but still takes like up to 7 seconds to show the window to the user.
When the window is shown, the user may already started doing something else or would try to perform the action again as nothing was happened in few seconds.

If I would as an end-user manually use the windows Run prompt (Win+R) with exaclty the same explorer.exe & path/arguments, the explorer window opens in less than 2 seconds, so the system isn't that slow by itself. From the cmd it takes like 4 seconds.

Is there any alternative to show an explorer window that selects a file (or just opens the desired directory path when you just give it as an argument) faster?

I know I'm giving unprecise timings, hope you get the idea.

Comment: have you tried `Process.Start(@"c:\test");`

Comment: I just tried your code on my PC and it took about a second which is about the same as running Explorer. I wonder if antivirus or something else on your PC is making it slower?

Comment: Does the parent above the path you are opening containing a large number of files? The /select switch selects the final entry in the parents view - perhaps you need to use /root?

Comment: @RuudHelderman It opens the window explorer on the partent dir of the file and selects the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I could gather, it was a combination of:

- VS Debugging
- Debug build
- Long time no reboot.

Other system operations were taking too long as well.
Changing all that did greatly improve the situation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, closing the anti-virus software helps the "process used time" reduced significantly